# Node js loop Time

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Estou executando essas funções abaixo em um `for`. A funcionalidade está quase fazendo o que eu desejo, porém gostaria de saber se teria como depois de executar `const q = await clientOut.write(p[i])`, esperar ao menos 3 segundos para depois continuar a percorrer o `for`. É possível fazer isso?

```js
const dadosMsg = await x.getValueMsg();

for(var i =0;i<dadosMsg.length;i++){

      c = await xmlTemplates.xml_16_begin(dadosMsg[i]);  

      const b = await clientOut.write(c);
      console.log(b+' >>>>>>>>>>Entrada');    
      const p = await xmlTemplates.xml_16_end();

      const q = await clientOut.write(p[i])
      console.log(q+' >>>>>>>>>>Saida');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar uma função `wait`, que retorna uma promessa que se resolverá depois de um certo tempo.

Algo assim:

```js
function wait(time = 0) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, time);
  });
}

// Usando em uma função assíncrona qualquer:
async function main() {
  console.log('Começo.');
  await wait(1500); // Espera 1,5 segundo (1500ms).
  console.log('Fim.');
}

main();
```

Se você está usando Node e quiser instalar um pacote para não implementar isso manualmente, pode usar o [`waait`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/waait).